# Invalid JSON convert to XML

Tags: json, xml, json.net

I am calling a 3rd party restAPI and getting back bad JSON what is the best way to fix the JSON:

```
{
"site": {
        "name":{"2":"stringstuff"},
        "primaryname":{"ref":2,"dname":"stringstuff"}       
    }
}
```

as you can see the name should actually look like the primary name.  When converted to XML it looks like this:

```
<sites>
    <name>
        <2>stringstuff</2>
    </name> 
    <primaryname>   
        <ref>2</ref>    
        <dname>stringstuff</dname>  
    </primaryname>
</sites>
```

Is there a less complicated way to fix this than converting to an Object, fixing the data that way and then converting the Object to XML

(Note I am using the Newtonsoft JSON.Net libraries and the requirement is that it must be returned from my web service as XML).

Comment: What do you mean by *Is there a less complicated way to fix this than converting to an Object...*?  What are you doing now, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Is there no chance of the 3rd party fixing their API?

Comment: Meaning is there a process that requires less steps, instead of creating a custom object to hold the  JSON, then fix, then convert to XML. Currently we are looping through a certain amount of times and any xml tags that are numeric we are adjusting the string then reloading the xml (which will eventually break when the numeric tags are greater than the loop as the tags are based off an increasing id number). 3rd party extremely slow to fix and we cannot wait.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say this json is invalid. It looks fine to me. I can convert it to XML using the XPath 3.1 json-to-xml() function and it comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <map key="site">
        <map key="name">
            <string key="2">stringstuff</string>
        </map>
        <map key="primaryname">
            <number key="ref">2</number>
            <string key="dname">stringstuff</string>
        </map>
    </map>
</map>
```

which you can readily transform using XSLT to anything else that you want